# how on ubuntu 12.04 writeon cd and read from cd

Tags: 12.04

I installed ubuntu 12.04.When

I put the disk in the drive of my computer icon of disk appears on desktop When I click on icon I receive images of several files and I don't know what to do with them.

I expected appearance of commands sach as "read" or   "Write".

I don't know how activate interaction with the disk. I am nonprofessional in computer science and programming. Simple user.

I would appreciate very much if somebody could explain in simple words how to activate interaction with CD and DVD in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: what kind of disk (audio, data etc.) do you want to open?

Comment: 'CD or DVD' -  READ THE QUESTION @qbi. I would try using k3b to WRITE to disks (installation instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K3b#Installation), and VLC media player to play DVDs or CDs. If it is just files on your disks, you should be able to open the disk in the file manager, and it should be in the pane on the left under computer or devices. From the sound, there are images on your disk, so this may be the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the perfect solution in the link below

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu